# Command CompileSwift failed on archiving build on Jenkins

Tags: xcode, jenkins, fastlane

In our project we have CI setup on M1 processor. We use fastlane to automate build publshing and Jenkins to run `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` + `bundle exec fastlane build` upond each commit. The local archive via fastalne works fine on M1 process. We don't have any problem with it. Once, we run our pipeline on CI the `Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code` appears. The errors reference to several files from third party libaries which added with cocoapods (Kingfisher, Stripe, FBSDKShareKit). Any thoughts why does the error reprodicible only on CI run not on local execution of the same commands via consloe?

cocoapods: 1.10.2

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved by myself. I figure out that my project has an inaccurate build script to rename image assets to lowercase. The build script has a "Based on dependency analysis" checkmark enabled. Consequently, upon clean install on Jenkins, it always failed, but in fact succeeded on the second run.